# Rails: Trigger and dispatch a event from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, headless

I am working on a Headless Rails Project, where Frontend is React and Rails server merely acts as API.

Now the issue I am facing is, that few routes are protected which checks the login timestamp of the user within a given timeframe.
Ex: To access the route "home"(/home). The user should have logged in the last 10 minutes. If not I need to send the event to the frontend, which will show a popup in the browser to sign in.

Is there rails friendly way to achieve this?
I don't want to redirect the user to the sign-in page.

Comment: Probably you can handle specifically Error (by code error or something like this) from BE and show popup on FE when you receive error by request

Comment: i think no need to send event from BE, just add a countdown time along with home response and start countdown on FE then show popup.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to return an empty head response from the controller:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    head :unauthorized if session_timed_out
  end
end
```

You could also run this as a before_filter and use it elsewhere in your app:

```rb
class AplicationController
  before_filter :return_unauthorized_if_session_timed_out
  def return_unauthorized_if_session_timed_out
    return head :unauthorized if session_timed_out
  end
end
```